# best practice to process data from html form with php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a loop i create form with, but the problem is im not sure how to pass the data from the form to the server.
this is my form:

```
  foreach ($appeals as $appeal) {
    $attached_file = $appeal["file_dir"];
    $output = '<div class="appeal">';
    $output .= '<div class="form-response"><form class="form-signin" method="post">';

    $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $output .= '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name"  value="'.$appeal['course_id'].'" required readonly/>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $output .= '<label>Student: '.$appeal['first_name']." ".$appeal['last_name'].'</label>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $output .= '<label>Submit Date: '.$appeal['submit_date'].'</label>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $output .= '<label>Message: '.$appeal['content'].'</label>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $output .= '<label for="response">Message:</label>';
    $output .= '<textarea class="form-control" name="response" rows="5" required></textarea>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<button type="submit" name="approve" value="'.$appeal['appeal_id'].'" class="btn btn-default">Approve</button>';
    $output .= '<button type="submit" name="decline" value="'.$appeal['appeal_id'].'" class="btn btn-default">Decline</button>';
    $output .= '</form></div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    echo $output;
  }
```

considering the fact i don't want the data to be visible in the client side, is there a way to add `onclick="someFunc(...)` to the submit buttons and than pass the variables from `$appeal` to this function without showing them in the client, or should i consider passing the data using AJAX, but than again how can i call a function with the data from `$appeal` without revealing it in the client side? thx

Comment: You forgot the `action` parameter in your form tag. The action parameter should contain an URL where you want to submit the data to and then process... Lets say something like `action="http://mywebsite.com/form_processor.php"` I don't understand what you try to say with: `i don't want the data to be visible in the client side` can you please explain that more in detail?

Comment: "i don't want the data to be visible in the client side" - i don't want user to be able to get the parameters im sending to the function with "inspect element" for example if using chrome

Comment: Instead of adding info in the comments, you should [edit] your question.

Comment: @yarivbar That's not possible.

Comment: so with parameter you mean `name="approve"`? if so, you could change it to what ever you want. lets say `approve` becomes `blabla`. or you change "approve" to a [hash value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) such as `sha1`, `md5()`. Either way, what ever your server sends to the client will always be visible in the source.